# RSS Viewer Web Part failing after installing KB2810059

Tags: 2010, rss

Our Rss feeds failed to load after installing this patch.

I added this script:
http://adammcewen.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/rss-viewer-web-part-failing-after-installing-kb2810059/

to the end of an existing .js file that loads in the page where we have the rss viewer feeds.

However, when I usef Developer tools to debug, I notice

```
_spPageContextInfo
```

is undefined, and therefore the code is never executed.

ANy idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: are you using a custom master page?

Comment: yes I think so,

Comment: ok, then maybe I know the cause of the problem. Give me a minute to post an answer. Keep in mind that this is only a guess based on a similar problem I experienced in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the August CU for SP 2010 fixed the RSS feeder webpart loading bug.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it would seem that your main problem is that the _spPageContextInfo variable is not defined. I don't know if this is your case, but in the past I found myself in a similar situation when working with a custom master page that someone else developed.

After some fun searching for a cause, a number of curses to the master page creation and some prayers to the Google Goddess, I found an article that explains the inner working behind the above variable and it's availability on SharePoint pages. The link is [here](http://blog.tedpattison.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9).

Short story: the **SPWebPartManager** control is responsible of defining the _spPageContextInfo variable. Since whoever created my master page forgot to add it, the problem was resolved by simply enough adding the missing control.. and presto! the variable appeared.

As said, I don't know if you are in the same situation, but I prefer to post this anyway in the hope it may help you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I just checked the masterpage and the control is here! damn!! :(, but very valuable info.

Comment: Sorry. I hoped it could be your problem. Anyway, any sign of the _spPageContextInfo variable if you look at the source code of the page?